# How do I build a registry search based on values in registry

Tags: properties, wix, registry

I have a registry value that holds the current version of a config to use

HKLM\SOFTWARE\companyname\productname\CurrentVersion = 13.5

I can successfully search for this and get its value using

```
<Property Id="CURRENTVERSION">
  <RegistrySearch Id="CurrentVersionID" Root="HKLM" Type="raw"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\companyname\productname\CurrentVersion"></RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

but now I need to search for another registry value based on this CURRENTVERSION value, located at

SOFTWARE\companyname\productname\CURRENTVERSION\ConfigPath

```
<Property Id="CONFIGPATH">
  <RegistrySearch Id="ConfigPathId" Root="HKLM" Type="raw"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\companyname\productname\CURRENTVERSION\ConfigPath"></RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

Can somebody provide me with a way to do this, preferably with an example.

Comment: if you found the correct answer below, please mark it as such.. it helps other users when they have a similar problem as yours identify the correct answer

Comment: Only just got back in from a trip away, solved my issue by using custom actions in the end as it was a lot easier to do more advanced registry manipulations than wix. marked yours as solution as it is more to do with wix but have not got around to trying out as had already found a custom action solution to my problem by the time my question was answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try enclosing CURRENTVERSION in your second registry search within [], as in:

```
<Property Id="CONFIGPATH">
    <RegistrySearch Id="ConfigPathId" Root="HKLM" Type="raw"
              Key="SOFTWARE\companyname\productname\[CURRENTVERSION]\ConfigPath">
    </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

I haven't tested it but this is how you normally access values of properties in WiX.

Alternatively, you can define variables in the RegistrySearch element in the Utils extension. These variables can then be used in other registry searches. Check out the following link for an example:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_define_searches.htm

Comment: According to the [RegLocator table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, the key is of type [RegPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371173(v=vs.85).aspx) which can indeed resolve properties. Whenever you are in doubt about what kind of syntax you can use in a wix attribute, it's best to refer to the documentation of the associated [windows installer tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368259(v=vs.85).aspx). They are linked in the wix documentation.

Comment: Thanks, useful info in there.

Comment: I have marked this answer the best one as it is the answer related to my question. However I solved it another way, by creating a custom action. This gave me a lot more freedom and ease to pass back and forth in properties my results.

Comment: Custom Actions do give a lot of freedom, but it is not recommended that you use Custom Actions if you can avoid them. According to Rob Mensching (the project lead for WiX), "Custom actions are (generally) an admission of failure" :-)